# Is there a O(n) way to draw a 2-D array grid instead of O(n²) in C?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, big-o

Is there a O(n) way to draw a 2-D array grid instead of O(n²) in C? For instance, I'm wondering if there's a way to use one `for` loop instead of two. I always felt like there was a way, but thought I'd turn it over to you...

```
ARRAY2D grid;

void ShowGrid(void)
{
    int x, y;

    for (y = 0; y < grid.height; y++)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < grid.width; x++)
        {
            printf("%d", arr2_get(&grid, x, y));
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Define N please. Is N the number of cells or is it X or Y?

Comment: This question is more easily answered if you don't use undefined symbols like `ARRAY2D` and `arr2_get`.

Comment: Isn't this O(n) regardless or am i missing something?

Comment: @Phil Maybe you want to ask how to do what you want with one `for`-loop instead of two? If this is what you want, you might want to remove the O-notation from your question. Just to clarify - the power of N inside the O-notation in *not* equal to the number of nested loops your program has.

Comment: You do realize that using one `for` loop instead of two doesn't fundamentally change the runtime, right? If you have to print `width x height` items, you have to print `width x height` items, whether you use one loop, or two. In other words, you **have** to do `width x height` work.

Comment: _you can assume what ARRAY2D and arr2_get does_  Seems a little ranty in response to someone trying to help you answer a question.  Why dont you just say its a struct with int members?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You normally study what happens as you increase the number of elements.

If that's the case here, the code you posted is O(N), not O(N<sup>2</sup>).

If the grid has 100 elements, the number of times `printf` will be called will be proportional to 100 (O(N)), not proportional to 10,000 (O(N<sup>2</sup>)).

If on the other handle you were studying what happens as you increase the number of rows or columns, visiting all the elements will be at least O(R*C) since you have R*C elements.

---

Note that you can flatten the two loops, but it doesn't change the complexity in the least:

```
void ShowGrid()
{
    const int H = grid.height;
    const int W = grid.width;
    int n;

    for (n = 0; n < H*W; ++n)
    {
        int y = n / W;
        int x = n % W;
        printf("%d", arr2_get(&grid, x, y));
        printf("\n") if x == W-1;
    }
}
```

Comment: However, if the array is a square matrix of N rows of N columns, the complexity is O(N*N) since you have N*N elements....

Comment: +1, please add depends on definition of N: elements or width.

Comment: There's two loops going on though, which my data structures book says would mark it has an O(n2) algorithm. I'm not really understanding.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Which doesn't matter. In O notation the N is the input size, not something you arbitrarily pick.

Comment: The N here would be number of elements, not the 2D array. You are working on each element of the array once, so you have O(N) complexity. You can use a single loop, heck, even zero loops to modify the array.

Comment: @Cubic: Order of the matrix?

Comment: @Cubic, Actually, it is arbitrary. For example, the best sort algorithms are actually O((N log N) * M) where N is the number of elements and M is the length of the strings, but we ignore the length of the strings since we don't care how the algorithm scales as the length of the strings increases. That means we arbitrarily decide to evaluate what happens as the number of elements increases.

Comment: @ikegami: Ah, okay. I counted how many times printf() is called, which was the same amount as grid.width*grid.height. That would be O(n), indeed. Looks are deceiving. Thanks.

Comment: @ikegami That's not arbitrary. The input size for a list of strings isn't the length of the list, but the combined length of all the strings in the list. You can only ignore the length of the list members if it's a constant (which in this case would be M... and multiplying times a constant is a no-op in big o notation).

Comment: @Cubic, M is not a constant. Sorting slows down as the length of the string increases. We arbitrarily decide to treat it as a constant because we get to arbitrarily decide what we want to study.

Comment: @ikegami: Strange though.. my book says "An example of an O(n2) function would be a for-loop with another for-loop nested inside." What you're saying that's not always the case, if I'm understanding, and it doesn't seem to be the case in my code either.

Comment: @Phil Your book is a terrible introduction to the O notation then. Doesn't surprise me, most books just gloss over it. If you nest 2 loops that both take n time then you get O(n^2) though.

I know it's not generally a constant, but you used it in your expression as if it was.

Comment: @Phil, You don't have two nested loops iterating over the same list. You have O(W)*O(H)=O(W*H). Is that O(N) or O(N^2)? As I explained in my answer, that depends on how you define N, N = number of elements, or N = maximum of width and height.

Comment: @Cubic, Re "but you used it in your expression as if it was", No, I didn't. Mostly because there's no such thing. You can't tell if it's a constant or not by how it's used.

Comment: @ikegami: Well, I might have to agree. Apparently he was a college student when writing this intro book for a well-known author. Anyway, I get it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The following code uses a single `for` loop:

```
void ShowGrid(void)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < grid.width * grid.height; i++)
    {
        int x = i % grid.width;
        int y = i / grid.width;

        printf("%d", arr2_get(&grid, x, y));

        if (x == grid.width - 1)    
            printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Another approach without multiplication or division:

```
void ShowGrid(void)
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    while (y < grid.height) {
        printf("%d", arr2_get(&grid, x, y));
        x += 1;

        if (x == grid.width) {
            printf("\n");
            x = 0;
            y += 1;
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

But the time complexity is obviously the same as with two `for` loops.

Comment: **Time complexity is obviously the same as with two for loops.** Worth repeating.

Comment: @nwellnhof: Thanks or the alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to structure your 2d matrix as a 1 dimensional array or your loop variables, which will allow you to use 1 loop. However, this will not reduce the run time complexity at all.

**In your situation, you are always going to have to access each cell of the 2d grid.**

If you define N = Width*Height. Your code is already O(n). If you define N = Width = Height, then your code is O(N^2). Neither of these can be improved.